# FORM number validation

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to do a validation for the `Quantity` It should run a `Function` validation to make sure that anything in the field is not less than 1 or has a decimal or letters or symbols. 
It should have an alert saying `Quantity should not be less than 1`

**FORM**

```
<Form method="post" action="qty.php">
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Qty" id="Qty" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>   
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="show_hide" id="submit" name="submit">add</button>

</form>
```

SOmething that below

**javascript**

```
function nonzero(val,wishlist)
{
    if(val.value<1 || val.value=='')
    {
        alert("Quantity should not be Zero or Null")
        val.value='1';
        val.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(wishlist==1){
        document.getElementById('option').value='wishlist';
        document.product26.submit();
    }
    else
    {
        return option_add('26');
    }
    //return true;
}
```

Comment: here is a start: [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Comment: @Emily - your qty.php doesn't seem to include any of the code from Ed's answer that you say isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use HTML 5

   `<input type="number" name="Qty" id="Qty" value="1" min="1" />`
2. Then use Javascript.
3. Then (and always do this bit) write some PHP for double check.

   `$qty = $_POST['qty'];

   if(!is_int($qty) || intval($qty) < 1) {
      echo 'Please provide an number only.';

   } else {
      $qty = intval($qty);
      // .... Etc
   }`

Comment: I have added more code cause i have try what u posted by it not  working

Comment: @Emily - what does 'it not working' mean? If you get an error message, add it to the question.

Comment: @andrewsi  I am not getting an error message... I am not getting any alert or echo. If I enter `0` or `decimal` or  `letter`

Comment: @Emily - your code includes `$_POST['pid']`; do you have a `pid` variable in your form? There isn't one in the HTML you've posted.

Comment: @andrewsi the pid is not for the qty is for the product id. I am only trying to validation the Quantity...

Comment: @Ed Heal please look at the javascript i just added

Answer (score 0):

Simply check in php if the qty is an INT :

```
  $qty = $_POST['qty'];

  if(!is_int($qty) || $qty < 0 ){
    echo 'Please provide an positive number only.';  
  }else{
    echo 'Im a number';
  }
```